# Unable to boot on centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, hard-disk, lsblk

Since today, I cannot boot into my Linux CentOS 7. I am directly taken to emergency mode.

I have tried the following commands without success:

`sudo umount /dev/sdb1` and `sudo fsck -p /dev/sdb1`

I have included the `journalctl` output for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The disk is reporting uncorrectable read errors with a subtype of "media error" - it looks like your disk is failing and some blocks of data are already unrecoverable.

It is very unlikely that disk can be fixed by software. Replace the disk and restore from backup.

If you don't have a backup, **stop** using that disk as running it may make the damage worse. Then decide if you want to use a professional data recovery service, or if you want to attempt recovery yourself.

If you want to try recovering the data yourself, get a replacement disk *and* a separate disk big enough to hold any data you might wish to recover. Then either boot the server using some external boot media that has `ddrescue` or a similar recovery-oriented cloning tool, or move the failing disk to another system as a second disk (so you can boot from a known-good system disk to recover data). Then, **make an image** of the damaged partition **as the first thing you do with the failing disk**. After imaging, disconnect the failing disk and keep it safe.

Once that's done, **work with the image** to recover your files. If you make a mistake or find out you are unable to recover some critical file from the image, you will be able to send the original to data recovery professionals, or retry imaging the failing disk yourself, while minimizing the chance of progressive damage to the original failing disk.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: do **not** power on this system ever again. Your HDD is physically dying, if there's a mechanical failure, trying to use it further may result in more damage to the platters.

1. If you have any valuable info on this HDD that you need to recover, send it to any serious service center which does data recovery.
2. If there's nothing valuable, well, smash the disk with a hammer and get rid of it.